LWC - New Correspondence Modal is not working
I have following code for my LWC component. It does not open modal window when I click "New Correspondence" button. I reviewed code so many time and couldn't find what is the issue here.
Any help or advice is welcome. Thank you!
<template>
<div class="button-container">
    <lightning-button class="new-correspondence-button" label="New Correspondence" onclick={showNewCorrespondenceModal}></lightning-button>
    <template if:true={hasExistingCorrespondences}>
        <lightning-button class="existing-correspondence-button" label="Select Existing Correspondence" onclick={handleSelectExisting}></lightning-button>
    </template>
</div>

<div class="correspondence-list-container">
    <template if:true={showCorrespondenceList}>
        <c-correspondence-list parent-id={recordId} oncorrespondenceselected={handleCorrespondenceSelected}></c-correspondence-list>
    </template>

    <template if:true={selectedCorrespondenceId}>
        <c-message-list correspondence-id={selectedCorrespondenceId} key={selectedCorrespondenceId}></c-message-list>
        <c-message-input correspondence-id={selectedCorrespondenceId} onmessagesent={handleMessageSent}></c-message-input>
    </template>
</div>

<template if:true={showNewCorrespondenceModal}>
    <c-new-correspondence-modal onclose={hideNewCorrespondenceModal} onsave={createNewCorrespondence}></c-new-correspondence-modal>
</template>

import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import createCorrespondence from '@salesforce/apex/MessageService.createCorrespondence';
import getCorrespondences from '@salesforce/apex/MessageService.getCorrespondences';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

export default class MessagingApp extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @api objectApiName;
    @track selectedCorrespondenceId;
    @track showCorrespondenceList = false;
    @track hasExistingCorrespondences = false;
    @track showNewCorrespondenceModal = false; // This is the tracked property to manage modal visibility

    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: '$objectApiName' })
    objectInfo;

    get objectType() {
        return this.objectInfo.data ? this.objectInfo.data.apiName : null;
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        console.log('connectedCallback called');
        this.checkExistingCorrespondences();
    }

    handleCorrespondenceSelected(event) {
        console.log('handleCorrespondenceSelected called with event:', event);
        this.selectedCorrespondenceId = event.detail;
        this.showCorrespondenceList = false;
    }

    showNewCorrespondenceModal() {
        console.log('showNewCorrespondenceModal called');
        this.showNewCorrespondenceModal = true; // Show the modal by setting the tracked property to true
        console.log('showNewCorrespondenceModal state:', this.showNewCorrespondenceModal);
    }

    hideNewCorrespondenceModal() {
        console.log('hideNewCorrespondenceModal called');
        this.showNewCorrespondenceModal = false; // Hide the modal by setting the tracked property to false
        console.log('showNewCorrespondenceModal state:', this.showNewCorrespondenceModal);
    }

    createNewCorrespondence(event) {
        console.log('createNewCorrespondence called with event:', event);
        const subject = event.detail.subject;
        if (!subject) {
            console.log('Subject is required');
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error',
                    message: 'Subject is required',
                    variant: 'error'
                })
            );
            return;
        }

        console.log('Creating correspondence with subject:', subject);

        createCorrespondence({
            parentId: this.recordId,
            parentObjectType: this.objectType,
            correspondenceName: subject
        })
        .then(correspondenceId => {
            console.log('Correspondence created with ID:', correspondenceId);
            this.selectedCorrespondenceId = correspondenceId;
            this.showNewCorrespondenceModal = false; // Hide the modal after creating the correspondence
            console.log('showNewCorrespondenceModal state:', this.showNewCorrespondenceModal);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error creating correspondence:', error);
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error',
                    message: 'Failed to create correspondence',
                    variant: 'error'
                })
            );
        });
    }

    handleSelectExisting() {
        console.log('handleSelectExisting called');
        this.showCorrespondenceList = true;
    }

    checkExistingCorrespondences() {
        console.log('checkExistingCorrespondences called');
        getCorrespondences({ parentId: this.recordId })
        .then(data => {
            console.log('Existing correspondences:', data);
            this.hasExistingCorrespondences = data.length > 0;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error fetching correspondences:', error);
        });
    }

    handleMessageSent() {
        console.log('handleMessageSent called');
        this.template.querySelector('c-message-list').refreshMessages();
    }
}



if you just place your new correspondence modal on its own, does it opens as a Modal? without the 

I'm betting that you are having issues either with the CSS of the SLDS modal, from this sample code you posted. Consider using the Modal API instead. This way you have the modal code separated from the parent component, and should be easier for you to debug this and other issues.
